# Substring usage in MYSQL with regular expression

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have the following postGreSQL code which I need to make it work on MYSQL

```
  v_start_date := to_date(substring( paramweek, '^...........'), 'DD Mon YYYY');
    v_end_date := to_date(substring( paramweek, '...........$'),'DD Mon YYYY');

where 
^ beginning of line
$ end of line

and paramweek is a character varying
```

**I have tried running but it doesn't give any o/p in MYSQL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_DATE()` isn't a known function in MySQL.  The closest is [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), which requires that the date format be given using the format specifiers documented under [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

[`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) is a known MySQL function, but its two-argument version takes the index position from which to cut the first argument.  There is no native MySQL function that can retrieve a substring from a regex match.  However, in this case you can merely use [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_right):

```sql
SET v_start_date := STR_TO_DATE( LEFT(paramweek, 11), '%d %b %Y'),
    v_end_date   := STR_TO_DATE(RIGHT(paramweek, 11), '%d %b %Y');
```